# (VBA) Why my worksheet gets very big, when I use the lock propertie to lock a big range?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a WorkSheet that's about 11MB big (85k rows, 70 columns). Then I run the following macro to unlock two ranges, safe my sheet and the sheet is then 87MB big. Why does that happen? And how can I change that?

PS: The ranges are very big

```
Sub unprotect()
    Dim lastRow, lastColumn, firstRow, firstColumn As Variant

    ActiveSheet.unprotect

    firstRow = 2
    firstColumn = 32
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row '85k
    lastColumn = 350

    With ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(firstRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 2))
    .Locked = False 'unlock the cells, so they can be edited in a protected sheet
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(firstRow, firstColumn), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
    .Locked = False
    End With

    ActiveSheet.protect 'protect the sheet so only unlocked cells can be edited
End Sub
```

Comment: which Excel file format do you use? `xls`, `xlsx/xlsm`, `xlsb`, …

Comment: I am using xlsm

Comment: Then give `xlsb` a try. This is a binary format and a way more efficient with bigger files than the XLM based `xlsx` and `xlsm` formats.

Comment: yes I knew that but nevertheless thank you :)
But my problem here is not about the file type.
For example: This `Cells.Locked = True` doesnt increase the file, but this `somebigrange.Locked = True` does. And I want to know why.

Comment: Why have you set `lastcolumn` to 350 if you only have 70 columns? Setting properties for large ranges is much less efficient than setting them for entire rows/columns.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, that helped indeed :) Why is it less efficient and why is there so much more hidden data? And do I have to accept the big data increase when I want it restricted to some ranges or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is that by setting the cells.locked to false you have gone from using 85K rows by 70 columns (about 6 million cells) to using 85k rows by somewhat less than 350 columns (just under 30 million cells) so a factor of 5 or so increase.

Comment: Ok thats right the size goes down to 20MB when I use only 70 columns, so thank you for that :) But still when I do `Cells.Locked = False` instead of `someBigRange.Locked = False` theres no increase in size. Why is that?

Comment: If you set a property for the entire sheet Excel does not need to modify individual cells, but if you set a property for lots but not all the cells then excel sets properties for each cell in the lots of cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Sub unprotect()

    Dim lastRow         as long
    dim lastColumn      as long
    dim firstRow        as long
    dim firstColumn     as long

    With ActiveSheet
        .unprotect

        firstRow = 2
        firstColumn = 32
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row '85k
        lastColumn = 350

        .Range(.Cells(firstRow, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 2)).Locked = False 
        .Range(.Cells(firstRow, firstColumn), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Locked = False
        .protect 
    End With

End Sub
```

Here is a bit about the Range Object - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567.aspx

If it does not work, use the following code, to remove the additional styles, if any:

```
Sub RemoveTheStyles()

    Dim style               As style
    Dim l_counter           As Long
    Dim l_total_number      As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    l_total_number = ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For l_counter = l_total_number To 1 Step -1

        Set style = ActiveWorkbook.Styles(l_counter)

        If (l_counter Mod 500 = 0) Then
            DoEvents
            Application.StatusBar = "Deleting " & l_total_number - l_counter + 1 & " of " & l_total_number & " " & style.Name
        End If

        If Not style.BuiltIn Then style.Delete

    Next l_counter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Debug.Print "READY!"

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

One of those two solutions should give some result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but sadly none of the two things worked out :(

Comment: @leon -  Can you try it on two different computers? It seems really strange.